# Can't pull RSS feeds from external SharePoint site

Tags: 2007, rss

My environment consists of SharePoint 2007 and the other server is owned by a different organization.  Their SP server is either 2007 or 2010.  There is no proxy set up on our end and I can get RSS feeds from an internal resource on the site (although that didn't seem to work yesterday).  Everywhere I have looked through online searches, and on this site, have shown the web.config file should be modified but that only pertains to proxy information.  I have anonymous access enabled on my site already which was recommended by another tutorial.  The feeds from the other organization are working on a site in one of our other locations so I don't believe it is a configuration issue on their end.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do the servers have internet access? Can you log onto the web front end and try to open the RSS feed?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet but I'll give that a shot and let you know.  The server does have internet access.

Comment: Next step would be to look into the ULS Logs. It would most certainly generate an error, including a stack trace and additional information.

Comment: I'm not able to connect to the external SP site from the browser in the server.  My boss thinks it's because the domain admin account used on the box doesn't have privileges to surf the web.  I've also checked the ULS Logs, which I meant to mention before, and all I see about RSS is "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary."